# strange compiling errors with Xcode 4.1 on Lion

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, compiler-errors, osx-lion

I just upgraded my Mac to Lion and then Xcode 4.1. My iPhone project which worked well with Xcode 4.0 had 401 errors in Xcode 4.1.

I googled the solution and got two useful ways.

- changed the complier from GCC 4.2 to LLVM 2.1.
- changed `#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"` to `#import <sqlite3.h>`

Now the number of errors reduced to 15, saying

> Expected function body after function declarator

on `OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE` in file Runtime.h, which is a built-in source file.

I tried to change iOS Deployment Target from iOS 3.0 to iOS 4.1 and set Other C Flags as

> -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=040100

But neither of them worked.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just look at the corresponding source lines where the errors occur and see what the problem is ? If you can't understand it then post these lines here, since we don't have too many mind-readers on SO.

Comment: @Paul R . The error is on the lines of the file `Runtime.h`, which is a built-in source file. the only content of the lines are `OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE`. For example `OBJC_EXPORT id object_copy(id obj, size_t size)
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0)
    OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE;
OBJC_EXPORT id object_dispose(id obj)
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0)
    OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and was able to resolve it by changing this

```
#import "/usr/include/objc/runtime.h"
```

to this

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

where ever I included this file.  This change appears backward compatible with 4.0.2 running under Snow Leopard as well.